# Adjust brightness of 7 inch Waveshare display

Tags: pi-2, hdmi, display

Is it possible to control the brightness or switch on and off the backlight of an Waveshare display via command line or a script?

I'm using the 7 inch version (rev2.1) with a resolution of 1024x600 on a Raspberry Pi 2. 
The display is connected via HDMI and a usb cable for touch capability.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to Waveshare directly and received the following information from them:

The official display you can control, the Waveshare you have to do the following `hack` by
wiring the pad in the image below to a GPIO pin on the Pi. You then can control the brightness with PWM signal on that GPIO pin.

[image: WaveShare-Mod]